# The naming rules for your virtual environments in Python

Tags: python, virtualenv, naming-conventions, virtual-environment

I'm looking for some sort of naming scheme for my *virtual environments*.

- How do you usually name them?
- Is there naming convention for python virtual environments?

Comment: Is it a good idea to use snake names for environments? E.g. asp; viper; cobra i.e.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are storing your environment inside the project folder some common names are `env`, `venv`, `.env`, `.venv`, but besides that, I don't think there are any common conventions.

The official docs.python.org's tutorial on [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html?highlight=prevents+clashing#creating-virtual-environments) also suggests using `.venv` as the name.

> A common directory location for a virtual environment is `.venv`.
>
> This name keeps the directory typically hidden in your shell and thus
> out of the way while giving it a name that explains why the directory
> exists.
>
> It also prevents clashing with `.env` environment variable
> definition files that some tooling supports.
>
> - *[docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html?highlight=prevents+clashing#creating-virtual-environments)*

Comment: I asked about the names not where to store environments. Because in the second case everything is obvious. You have only 2 options. To keep them in the project folder or in a central location.

Comment: I use [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) to manange my virtual environments and store the venvs in the projects folder so the folder name essentially serves as the name of venv too.